# Using SVG code, how can I add white space to the top of my SVG image?

Tags: html, css, svg

Let's say I have an SVG like below, how could I add 10px padding to the top of the image?  I've tried using `style="padding-top: 10px"` and `transform="translate(0,10px)"`, but both end up cropping the bottom by 10px.  Adjusting the viewport dimensions did not fix the cropping for me.

Note, I want to do this in the SVG code, not using external style.  I thought it would be an easy tweak, but no..?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 440.11 132.63">
  <path fill="#fcaf17" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M273.04 103.72c-25.57 18.87-62.64 28.9-94.57 28.9A171.14 171.14 0 0 1 62.95 88.56c-2.38-2.16-.25-5.12 2.63-3.45 32.89 19.2 73.6 30.68 115.6 30.68a229.73 229.73 0 0 0 88.16-18.05c4.32-1.83 7.95 2.86 3.72 6"/>
  <path fill="#fcaf17" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M283.68 91.57c-3.27-4.19-21.62-2-29.87-1-2.49.3-2.87-1.88-.62-3.45 14.63-10.29 38.61-7.31 41.4-3.88s-.73 27.52-14.45 39c-2.11 1.77-4.12.81-3.18-1.51 3.09-7.71 10-25 6.72-29.16"/>
  <path fill="#231f20" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M254.4 14.48v-10a2.48 2.48 0 0 1 2.53-2.54h44.78a2.5 2.5 0 0 1 2.58 2.53v8.56c0 1.43-1.22 3.31-3.38 6.29l-23.18 33.12c8.6-.21 17.72 1.08 25.53 5.48a4.54 4.54 0 0 1 2.37 3.9v10.66c0 1.47-1.6 3.17-3.28 2.27a51.59 51.59 0 0 0-47.31.1c-1.57.82-3.19-.85-3.19-2.32V62.42a12 12 0 0 1 1.66-6.87L280.38 17h-23.39a2.49 2.49 0 0 1-2.59-2.52M91.08 76.88H77.46a2.56 2.56 0 0 1-2.44-2.3V4.66a2.57 2.57 0 0 1 2.64-2.51h12.68a2.56 2.56 0 0 1 2.48 2.35v9.13h.26C96.38 4.8 102.61.68 111 .68s13.86 4.12 17.68 12.95C131.98 4.8 139.48.68 147.49.68a19.32 19.32 0 0 1 15.77 7.63c4.32 5.87 3.44 14.41 3.44 21.92v44.11a2.57 2.57 0 0 1-2.63 2.52h-13.62a2.55 2.55 0 0 1-2.44-2.51V37.31c0-2.94.25-10.29-.39-13.09-1-4.71-4.07-6-8-6a9 9 0 0 0-8.14 5.74c-1.41 3.49-1.3 9.35-1.3 13.35v37.06a2.57 2.57 0 0 1-2.63 2.52h-13.58a2.55 2.55 0 0 1-2.44-2.51V37.31c0-7.79 1.26-19.27-8.4-19.27s-9.41 11.18-9.41 19.27v37.06a2.56 2.56 0 0 1-2.62 2.52M342.83.67c20.22 0 31.15 17.37 31.15 39.43 0 21.33-12.08 38.25-31.15 38.25-19.84 0-30.64-17.36-30.64-39 0-21.78 10.93-38.7 30.64-38.7m.13 14.27c-10 0-10.68 13.68-10.68 22.21s-.12 26.79 10.55 26.79S353.9 49.2 353.9 40.23c0-5.89-.26-12.95-2-18.54-1.53-4.85-4.58-6.77-8.9-6.77M400.18 76.88h-13.55a2.56 2.56 0 0 1-2.44-2.51V4.42a2.59 2.59 0 0 1 2.63-2.27h12.63a2.58 2.58 0 0 1 2.42 1.95v10.69h.25C405.94 5.23 411.28.68 420.68.68c6.11 0 12.08 2.2 15.9 8.24 3.57 5.58 3.57 15 3.57 21.77v44a2.6 2.6 0 0 1-2.62 2.21h-13.68a2.58 2.58 0 0 1-2.43-2.21v-38c0-7.64.9-18.82-8.52-18.82a8.9 8.9 0 0 0-7.88 5.59c-1.9 4.26-2.17 8.52-2.17 13.23v37.65a2.6 2.6 0 0 1-2.65 2.52M218.71 43.49c0 5.31.12 9.73-2.55 14.45-2.17 3.83-5.6 6.19-9.43 6.19-5.23 0-8.29-4-8.29-9.88 0-11.59 10.41-13.7 20.27-13.7zm13.73 33.21a2.8 2.8 0 0 1-3.21.32c-4.53-3.76-5.34-5.5-7.81-9.07-7.48 7.61-12.78 9.9-22.46 9.9-11.47 0-20.39-7.08-20.39-21.24 0-11.05 6-18.57 14.52-22.26 7.4-3.24 17.72-3.83 25.62-4.71v-1.77c0-3.26.25-7.09-1.66-9.88-1.65-2.52-4.84-3.54-7.65-3.54-5.19 0-9.8 2.66-10.95 8.18a2.85 2.85 0 0 1-2.36 2.5l-13.2-1.43a2.39 2.39 0 0 1-2-2.84c3-16 17.5-20.86 30.46-20.86 6.62 0 15.29 1.77 20.51 6.78 6.63 6.19 6 14.45 6 23.45v21.22c0 6.38 2.65 9.17 5.15 12.62.86 1.24 1.06 2.71-.05 3.61a531.33 531.33 0 0 0-10.48 9.06zM40.18 43.49c0 5.31.12 9.73-2.55 14.45-2.17 3.83-5.6 6.19-9.43 6.19-5.23 0-8.29-4-8.29-9.88 0-11.59 10.42-13.7 20.27-13.7zM53.91 76.7a2.8 2.8 0 0 1-3.21.32c-4.53-3.76-5.34-5.5-7.82-9.07-7.47 7.61-12.76 9.9-22.45 9.9C8.97 77.85.04 70.77.04 56.61c0-11.05 6-18.57 14.53-22.26 7.39-3.24 17.71-3.83 25.61-4.71v-1.77c0-3.26.26-7.09-1.66-9.88-1.65-2.52-4.84-3.54-7.65-3.54-5.19 0-9.81 2.66-10.94 8.18a2.87 2.87 0 0 1-2.36 2.5L4.37 23.7a2.4 2.4 0 0 1-2-2.84C5.37 4.86 19.87 0 32.83 0c6.62 0 15.29 1.77 20.52 6.78 6.63 6.19 6 14.45 6 23.45v21.22c0 6.38 2.65 9.17 5.14 12.62.87 1.24 1.06 2.71 0 3.61a599.2 599.2 0 0 0-10.44 9.06z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I once did something similar by inserting the svg inside of an img tag (but it was base64 encoded. Once it is like that you can just add margins and paddings to your img tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just alter the viewBox. You might need to experiment a bit to find the values you need.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 -20 440.11 152.63">
  <path fill="#fcaf17" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M273.04 103.72c-25.57 18.87-62.64 28.9-94.57 28.9A171.14 171.14 0 0 1 62.95 88.56c-2.38-2.16-.25-5.12 2.63-3.45 32.89 19.2 73.6 30.68 115.6 30.68a229.73 229.73 0 0 0 88.16-18.05c4.32-1.83 7.95 2.86 3.72 6"/>
  <path fill="#fcaf17" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M283.68 91.57c-3.27-4.19-21.62-2-29.87-1-2.49.3-2.87-1.88-.62-3.45 14.63-10.29 38.61-7.31 41.4-3.88s-.73 27.52-14.45 39c-2.11 1.77-4.12.81-3.18-1.51 3.09-7.71 10-25 6.72-29.16"/>
  <path fill="#231f20" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M254.4 14.48v-10a2.48 2.48 0 0 1 2.53-2.54h44.78a2.5 2.5 0 0 1 2.58 2.53v8.56c0 1.43-1.22 3.31-3.38 6.29l-23.18 33.12c8.6-.21 17.72 1.08 25.53 5.48a4.54 4.54 0 0 1 2.37 3.9v10.66c0 1.47-1.6 3.17-3.28 2.27a51.59 51.59 0 0 0-47.31.1c-1.57.82-3.19-.85-3.19-2.32V62.42a12 12 0 0 1 1.66-6.87L280.38 17h-23.39a2.49 2.49 0 0 1-2.59-2.52M91.08 76.88H77.46a2.56 2.56 0 0 1-2.44-2.3V4.66a2.57 2.57 0 0 1 2.64-2.51h12.68a2.56 2.56 0 0 1 2.48 2.35v9.13h.26C96.38 4.8 102.61.68 111 .68s13.86 4.12 17.68 12.95C131.98 4.8 139.48.68 147.49.68a19.32 19.32 0 0 1 15.77 7.63c4.32 5.87 3.44 14.41 3.44 21.92v44.11a2.57 2.57 0 0 1-2.63 2.52h-13.62a2.55 2.55 0 0 1-2.44-2.51V37.31c0-2.94.25-10.29-.39-13.09-1-4.71-4.07-6-8-6a9 9 0 0 0-8.14 5.74c-1.41 3.49-1.3 9.35-1.3 13.35v37.06a2.57 2.57 0 0 1-2.63 2.52h-13.58a2.55 2.55 0 0 1-2.44-2.51V37.31c0-7.79 1.26-19.27-8.4-19.27s-9.41 11.18-9.41 19.27v37.06a2.56 2.56 0 0 1-2.62 2.52M342.83.67c20.22 0 31.15 17.37 31.15 39.43 0 21.33-12.08 38.25-31.15 38.25-19.84 0-30.64-17.36-30.64-39 0-21.78 10.93-38.7 30.64-38.7m.13 14.27c-10 0-10.68 13.68-10.68 22.21s-.12 26.79 10.55 26.79S353.9 49.2 353.9 40.23c0-5.89-.26-12.95-2-18.54-1.53-4.85-4.58-6.77-8.9-6.77M400.18 76.88h-13.55a2.56 2.56 0 0 1-2.44-2.51V4.42a2.59 2.59 0 0 1 2.63-2.27h12.63a2.58 2.58 0 0 1 2.42 1.95v10.69h.25C405.94 5.23 411.28.68 420.68.68c6.11 0 12.08 2.2 15.9 8.24 3.57 5.58 3.57 15 3.57 21.77v44a2.6 2.6 0 0 1-2.62 2.21h-13.68a2.58 2.58 0 0 1-2.43-2.21v-38c0-7.64.9-18.82-8.52-18.82a8.9 8.9 0 0 0-7.88 5.59c-1.9 4.26-2.17 8.52-2.17 13.23v37.65a2.6 2.6 0 0 1-2.65 2.52M218.71 43.49c0 5.31.12 9.73-2.55 14.45-2.17 3.83-5.6 6.19-9.43 6.19-5.23 0-8.29-4-8.29-9.88 0-11.59 10.41-13.7 20.27-13.7zm13.73 33.21a2.8 2.8 0 0 1-3.21.32c-4.53-3.76-5.34-5.5-7.81-9.07-7.48 7.61-12.78 9.9-22.46 9.9-11.47 0-20.39-7.08-20.39-21.24 0-11.05 6-18.57 14.52-22.26 7.4-3.24 17.72-3.83 25.62-4.71v-1.77c0-3.26.25-7.09-1.66-9.88-1.65-2.52-4.84-3.54-7.65-3.54-5.19 0-9.8 2.66-10.95 8.18a2.85 2.85 0 0 1-2.36 2.5l-13.2-1.43a2.39 2.39 0 0 1-2-2.84c3-16 17.5-20.86 30.46-20.86 6.62 0 15.29 1.77 20.51 6.78 6.63 6.19 6 14.45 6 23.45v21.22c0 6.38 2.65 9.17 5.15 12.62.86 1.24 1.06 2.71-.05 3.61a531.33 531.33 0 0 0-10.48 9.06zM40.18 43.49c0 5.31.12 9.73-2.55 14.45-2.17 3.83-5.6 6.19-9.43 6.19-5.23 0-8.29-4-8.29-9.88 0-11.59 10.42-13.7 20.27-13.7zM53.91 76.7a2.8 2.8 0 0 1-3.21.32c-4.53-3.76-5.34-5.5-7.82-9.07-7.47 7.61-12.76 9.9-22.45 9.9C8.97 77.85.04 70.77.04 56.61c0-11.05 6-18.57 14.53-22.26 7.39-3.24 17.71-3.83 25.61-4.71v-1.77c0-3.26.26-7.09-1.66-9.88-1.65-2.52-4.84-3.54-7.65-3.54-5.19 0-9.81 2.66-10.94 8.18a2.87 2.87 0 0 1-2.36 2.5L4.37 23.7a2.4 2.4 0 0 1-2-2.84C5.37 4.86 19.87 0 32.83 0c6.62 0 15.29 1.77 20.52 6.78 6.63 6.19 6 14.45 6 23.45v21.22c0 6.38 2.65 9.17 5.14 12.62.87 1.24 1.06 2.71 0 3.61a599.2 599.2 0 0 0-10.44 9.06z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: wow.  I could have sworn I already tried this - obviously I didn't get the values right.  Thanks for the clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I had to convert the svg file to base 64 and insert it inside of an image tag with a style:

```
<img alt="logo" style="padding-top:10px" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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">
```